# SQLite: are pragma statements undone by rolling back transactions?

Tags: sqlite, transactions, pragma

Just wondering whether pragmas such as foreign_keys = OFF, and VACUUM would be undone if included in a transaction which gets rolled back.

The online documentation doesn't seem to cover this...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is different for different pragma statements.

For example, SQLite version 3.7.15.2 includes the pragma 'user_version' in transactions and will COMMIT and ROLLBACK the value.

However, the same version of SQLite specifically excludes (in documentation and testing) foreign_keys from transactions.

It appears, from my limited sampling, that pragma that are not documented as invalid during transactions (foreign_key) will participate in the transaction (like user_version.)

PS: I realize this is a very old question, but it is where Google brought me when I needed this information.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you find a reference for this or was this just from trying it from the sqlite command line interface for some version?

Comment: Combination of this document https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html and testing. The documentation lists many of the pragma-transaction interactions, but doesn't list all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does not cover what happens with pragma statements issued inside transactions in general, but it does cover the subject for [foreign_keys](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) (and possibly for others):

> This pragma is a no-op within a transaction; foreign key constraint
>   enforcement may only be enabled or disabled when there is no pending
>   BEGIN or SAVEPOINT.

VACUUM is not a pragma, and the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) does cover transactions:

> A VACUUM will fail if there is an open transaction, or if there are
>   one or more active SQL statements when it is run.

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that at least the following PRAGMA is not valid within a transaction:

```
PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;
```

If attempted, you will receive some flavor of the following error message:

> SQL logic error: cannot change into wal mode from within a transaction